# Updateall from what search returned

Tags: php, yii

I'm absolute beginner in Yii and i find it quite hard to get deeper in these waters. Anyway my problem is that i manage to make a search() to filter what i need and then I want to update one col to something specific from what search returned , here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['Manual']))
    $m->attributes=$_POST['Manual'];
$m->search();
```

I checked that search() returns what i need but i cant write the update query. Here is how i tried...
`$m()->updateAll(array('toname'=>'123456'), $res);`
Any advices are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updateAll function works with the below syntax.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition( "id" , $ids ) ; // $ids = array ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
YourModel::model()->updateAll(array('toname'=>123456),$criteria);
```

What is $res in your code ?

Comment: will it affect only to search rows

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add criteria. Do it that way. I have edited my solution.

Comment: $ids in my solution are basically what you get from search. Make sure you write the correct column name ("id" in my case)..